# How to choose appropriate chunkSize and numDirectArenas for netty

Tags: java, netty

It there any documentation or article about that params?
How to choose **numDirectArenas** and **maxOrder** relatively to **maxDirectMemory** or load or some another requirements of my application?

```
-Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory=1000
-Dio.netty.allocator.numHeapArenas=0 
-Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=2 
-Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder=10
```

Answer (score -2):

Usually its fine to just use the default values. What exactly is a good limit for you depends a lot on the resources that you have on the system and also on the allocation patterns of your application.